# How to animate a collapsable tableview in a CollectionViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make my tableView that is nested in a CollectionViewCell animate when it collapses and expands like in the FotMob app:  [FotMob example](https://youtube.com/shorts/ZvWa_TczIFc?feature=share)

When I try this it just either don't animate or just does some weird shit. Here is some of my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return indexPath.row == 0 ? 70 : 120
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     let section = sections[section]
                    
     if section.isOpened {
         return section.fixtures.count + 1
     }
     else {
         return 1
     }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        sections[indexPath.section].isOpened.toggle()
        tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Btw the tableView is insetGrouped. Here is an image of my TableViewCell (btw it is not finished): [image: Here is an image of my TableViewCell. Note it is not finished :)] It is also possible to have more than more section. How can I get my tableView to animate like the FotMob example above.

Comment: You specify no animation in reloadSections(… with: .none)  . Also, collection view or table view ?

Comment: Yeah but I have tried all of them and none of them give the right animation for me. But I saw someone who did this with just a tableview and it animated fine with .none. And the tableview is inside a CollectionViewCell.

Comment: Why using table view cell inside collection view cell ? Look at diffable data source. ([sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views))

Comment: I have a tableview in a CollectionViewCell because I have a app where I have a collectionview that with 13 cells (for different dates) where 1 fills the whole screen and I can swipe between them and in the cells I have a tableview to display the data for my app.

Comment: @KristofferMelen - that sounds much better suited for `UIPageViewController`

Comment: Could you please provide more context how your UITableViewCell looks like?

Comment: @DonMag - Yeah, that sounds smart! omg. I am a bit stupid.

Comment: @swiftIos - Yeah I can do that.

Comment: @DonMag - It worked great now. I think the collection view is some how limited with its animations. Thank you so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

To have the kind of effect in the example you stated.
You can replace

```
tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
```

with

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

This will animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.